# Unexpected results while printing a string

Tags: c, arrays, string

I created a program in which i declared two arrays of char type. One would store the string and another would store the reversed string.But when i print the second array it displays some unexpected results.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
char a[] = "Sahib";
char b[5];
int i = 0;
int j,k = 0;
char c='a';
while(c!='\0'){
    c = a[i];
    i++;
}
i -= 2;
for(j=i;j<=0;j--){
    b[k] = a[j];
    k++;
}

printf("The reversed character is %s",b);
}
```

Comment: C strings are null terminated... You need to 1) provide space for it in the receiving variable and 2) you have to add it to the string yourself.

Comment: try `char b[sizeof(a)]={0}`, this is a helping push up.

Comment: Ya i added it ... still it is not displaying anything in place of b.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char a[] = "Sahib";
    char b[sizeof a];
    int i = 0;
    int j,k = 0;
    char c;

    while((c = a[i]) != '\0'){
        i++;
    }
    for(j = --i; j>=0; --j){
        b[k++] = a[j];
    }
    b[k] = '\0';

    printf("The reversed character is %s\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```